# eclipse now shows "add breackpoint" when hovering over an error

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse neon to program in Java.

Im talking about the veritical bar on the left where it shows the little error icon.  Normally I would go hover over it and it would show a description and I could click to see automatic resolutions.

Then I decided I would be adventurous and play with some editor settings...

Now somehow when I hover over the error icon what pops up is a small box with 2 icons.  a breakpoint icon and an error icon.  the breakpoint icon is always right under my mouse.  so if I just click again it adds a breakpoint.  So now I have to go hover over the problem icon, then that thing pops up then I need to move over to the right just a tad to get back over the problem description before I can see the popup for that and/or click it to see the auto-resolutions.

screenshot

[image]

Anyone have any idea what setting I messed with that caused this so I can undo it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable `"Expand vertical ruler icons upon hovering"` option in `Windows > Preferences > Java > Editors > Hovers`

Note that the change will take effect only after closing and reopening the editor.

See this [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=317939) for more details.

Comment: You are most welcome. Keep asking good questions and writing good answers.